# How to separate 'or' and 'and' in sql?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have this at the end of my query

```
  where bn.bin = '217' or bnque.bin = '217'
  and not exists(select 1 from emp_names where bn.own_code = ow.own_code or bnque.own_code = ow.own_code);
```

my problem is when I run this query it reads this format

```
  where bn.bin = '217' 
  or 
  bnque.bin = '217' and not exists(select 1 from emp_names where bn.own_code = ow.own_code or bnque.own_code = ow.own_code);
```

what i want is something like this

```
  where bn.bin = '217' and not exists(select 1 from emp_names where bn.own_code = ow.own_code);
  or 
  bnque.bin = '217' and not exists(select 1 from emp_names where bnque.own_code = ow.own_code);
```

and this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your query doesn't really make sense.  Don't you want a *correlation* in the subquery?  Something like this:

```
where (bn.bin = '217' or bnque.bin = '217') and
      not exists (select 1
                  from emp_names en
                  where bn.own_code = en.own_code or bnque.own_code = en.own_code
                 );
```

Comment: it only insert once but when I tried to input again using different bin, 0 rows inserted